# Separate Crawl Farm and UPS Configuration

Tags: 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, crawl, ups

SharePoint 2016 Enterprise. We have a dedicated crawl farm continuously crawling our content farm. Where do I need to provision the User Profile Service? On the crawl farm or the content farm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have same kind of topology, where

- User Profile Sync & Mysite & content in single farm. (for all social features, Manage Metadata related stuff...this will help)
- Search is in Own Farm
- Build the trust between Content & Search farm.

Comment: So just configuring the crawl farm to search the sps3s of the webapp tied to the UPS on the content farm will work?

Comment: that's correct. something like this sps3s://mysite.com, it is your mysite webapplication